# Saving static instance of Main - Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

So I need to access information from my document(Main.as) class.
I tried making this easy by saving a static instance of my Main class.

```
private static var _instance:Main;
public static function get instance():Main { return _instance; }

public function Main() {
    _instance = this;
}
```

Then when in another class I try to use this I get a null reference error.

```
public function InputController():void {
    main = Main.instance;
    main.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, OnKeyPress);
    main.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, OnKeyRelease);
}
```

I get an error on the `main.stage.addEventListener` lines.

Comment: stage is my main suspect. `trace(main, main.stage)` at the second line of your function.

Comment: @JohanLindkvist 1009 of course.

Comment: I don't get this error when i'm trying. Make sure your Main class is the document class and add some trace in the contructors to see if they are getting created.

Comment: So inside Main itself if I trace both this and _instance I see that both exist. however in the trace window the error comes before the trace meaning that the other classes are trying to access the variable before it's been set

Comment: @R4VANG3R That shouldn't happen. The document class should be the first class to be constructed. I don't know how it is if you are mixing with timeline code. How do you create the class with the InputController function?

Comment: I have no code in the timeline itself but the InputController class is instantiated inside Main. However I've found a way around this bug by getting my Player object from the stage and making it through code in Main's constructor. Now the order of instantiation is how I would think it'd go.

Answer (score 0):

If you have timeline coding, you can instantiate your static variable with `_instance=this` (should be accessible, as main timeline is a part of document class) at the first keyframe, and reference there from elsewhere via property.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to return an instance without instantiating it. Use the following code for instantiating the class first.

```
private static var _instance:Main;
public static function get instance():Main 
{ 
  if(_instance == null)
    _instance = new Main();
  return _instance; 
}
```

Comment: Should not work, as this instance is pretty much never used. OP needs to get easy reference to an already existing instance of Main, not to create a new one.